# Using AD in windows Azure for user account management

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Has anyone implemented a project using Azure for user registration and authentication?

I can see how it would work well in an Enterprise application, but it seems as if there is no easy way to enable "self registration"

It looks like it is intended to work with an on premises AD solution, or alternatively for new users to be added using the Azure management portal.

Can anyone give me the benefit of their experience?

Answer (score 0):

WAAD is a fully implemented solution for what I think you are trying to do, but created in a way very different than the "Active Directory" server product that it shares a name with.  Take a look at the **Windows Azure Active Directory Graph API**, which is the RESTful management API for WAAD. With Graph API you would be able to create a fully functional application authenication system to meet your needs.

**Overview**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974482.aspx

**API Reference**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974478.aspx

**Links, Examples, etc**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much, I was wondering if anyone had actually used this for an app?

Comment: I've used it for some internal applications with success.  Over time I suspect WAAD will become "the .NET way" to handle authenication, just needs a bit of time to get there.  Eventually I beleive you will be able to do everything you do with on-prem AD (manage devices, user, etc) from the cloud using WAAD.  From there, usage will skyrocket b/c running internal/LOB apps in the cloud with auth will be trivial due to WAAD.